# Resources for learning Qlik Sense

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am learning a qlik sense tool. I googled about this to learn or understand its controls/widgets, but didn't find much resources and explanations. The only one website where I found example code is https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/2.1/Subsystems/Platform/Content/qlik-sense-platform.htm

May somebody suggest other resources with example code? Is there any book with understandable examples?

Comment: You might also find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756903/qlikview-and-qliksense-vs-msbi helpful

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried their YouTube channel? [Qlik](https://www.youtube.com/user/qlikview)

Qlik Sense is a relatively young product that is still being developed so the number of resources are still relatively small.

That being said, the engine behind Sense is the same as Qlikview, and there are lots of resources that can be found online such as this one [37 blogs to help with QV](http://www.askqv.com/blogs/) and my [own](http://oneqlikatatime.blogspot.co.uk/). The expressions and data manipulation elements are directly comparable - quite often if I can't make something work in Sense data load editor I will work it out in View first and then transfer the script directly.

Answer (score 3):

Qlik Sense release 3.0 is slated for release on July 28 (2016). I hope it improves some of the constraints I'm facing with the front-end UI.

For example.. My client wants charts with tons of columns, with the additional requirement that the data must be easily exportable to Excel. Standard tables in Qlik Sense can be exported, but they don't allow easy access to the columns that don't fit on the screen. Pivot tables allow users to scroll horizontally to see hidden columns, but the data in this object can't be exported to Excel.

If you're working on calculation logic, I think that this YouTube video is a must-see: "Beginners' Introduction to Set Analysis - Qlik Sense and QlikView" https://youtu.be/YMQJnKMkfxg

Answer (score 2):

Me too, I struggled to understand what QlikSense is all about and how it compares to existing solutions such as Excel, Python, R (Shiny), or Tableau. At least I now understood the difference to QlikView which I want to share with everybody:

**QlikView pre-cans more than QlikSense**, i.e. it gives a data scientist less freedom to set up dashboards etc. In other words: Developers think about a data model, the charts, tables and the overall front-end layout, and the (business) user just consumes the fairly-fixed user interface.

Concerning web resources, I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYZ-7UG6UC8 helpful to see QlikSense in action.

**Disclaimer:** I am **not** associated with the company Qlik, I am just trying to get a not-too-subjective understanding of QlikSense's capabilities.