# Histogram of aggregated dimension in QlikSense?

Tags: histogram, qlikview, qliksense

A simple, but yet frequent statistics is a histogram of derived entity, and if I understand the [official QlikSense documentation](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-cloud/Subsystems/CloudHub/Content/Sense_Hub/Visualizations/Histogram/histogram.htm) right that seems not working out of the box:

> You cannot use a master dimension that was created using the
>   expression editor, even if the resulting field is numeric. The
>   dimension cannot be based on an aggregation function.

Assume I have some mockup-data of basic user data looking like this:

```
id  first_name  last_name   gender  date_added  nickname
1   Marthe      Salzburg    Female  2018-03-27  msalzburg0
2   Larine      Camm        Female  2018-05-13  lcamm1
3   Leanor      MacIan              2018-05-13  lmacian2
4   Shawnee     Baudain     Female  2018-01-08  sbaudain3
5   Mable       Sitlinton   Female  2018-03-27  msitlinton4
6   Jilleen     Wadesworth  Female  2018-04-12  jwadesworth5
7   Mace        Lube        Male    2018-11-18  mlube6
```

Plotting how many user registered each day is easy: Add a new bar plot to your QlikView sheet, choose `date_added` as dimension and `Count([date_added.autoCalendar.Date])` as measure, et volià:
[image]

The next logical question to ask is: On how many days have been `x` users added? The answer I expect from the mock data above would be something like:

```
  added_per_day occurences
  2             2
  1             3
  0             309  # (number of days between 2018-01-08 and 2018-11-18) - 5
```

My question: **How do I do generate such a histogram with QlikSense?**

As [mentioned in answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619242/), my challenge is that the active QlikSense community seems to be rather small, that why I am asking here.  I am new to the software, I am rather used to the command-line approach.

Comment: what is the logic behind "added_per_day" and "occurences"? it is not clear

Comment: It is a histogram showing how many days with 2, 1 or 0 users are added per day.

Comment: have you looked at the aggr chart function?

Comment: I looked at https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2018/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/aggr.htm May you give me a concrete example for my problem, please?

Answer (score 1):

So you need something like this in your load script:

```
Load date_added, count(date_added) as Added_Per_Date
resident Data
group by date_added;
```

to that you will need to add all the dates that are not used...

and then in your chart use `Added_Per_Date` as dimension and `count(Added_Per_Date)` as expression

Comment: I will try to learn about load scripts as described https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2018/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptRegularStatements/Load.htm May you please elaborate a bit on what your load-script does and how to expand the data-series (within QlikSense)?

Comment: There many tutorials online, here is one. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Pl9QKCifUTg